# Task scheduler not producing output with powershell script

Tags: python, powershell, scheduled-tasks, windows-task-scheduler

I have a basic task through Task Scheduler that calls a Powershell script that executes a Python Script.  For some reason when I call the Powershell script through Task Scheduler it produces no output, when I look at the History logs it also successfully finishes as well.  I am able to manually run the Powershell script through the terminal and everything works.  Has anyone else had this issue? Thanks!

Here are my "Edit Actions" paramters:

Program/script:
`C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`

Add arguments (optional):
`-ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\MyFolderName\MyPowerShellScript.ps1`

Start in (optional):
`C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\MyFolderName\`

The task is also configured in `Windows Vista, Windows Server 2008` and will `Run whether user is logged on or not`

Here is what is in my .ps1 script:

```
$Path = "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\MyFolderName"
cd $Path
pipenv run python "main.py"
```

*edit I am getting error code 0x1 as the `Last Run Result`, it should be 0x0

Comment: Please, where's your Powershell script?

Comment: @MarcSances ```C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\MyFolderName\MyPowerShellScript.ps1```

Comment: I mean that you should paste the code of that script so we can see if it is related somehow....

Comment: @MarcSances The Powershell script works when I run it manually, it's just not working when I execute it with Task Scheduler.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code. We need a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to help you out

Comment: @MarcSances I added the .ps1 script to my question.

Comment: Where is the output supposed to be produced to?

Comment: I use an API to retrieve some data and it saves the output to an .XLSX (excel file)

Comment: Which is located in another folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the arguments option has worked:

Add arguments (optional):

`-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -file "C:\Users\MyUserName\Documents\MyFolderName\MyPowerShellScript.ps1"`